# update application state(global variables) from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, process, state, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I've been searching and reading and not fond a concise answer that fits what I need so hopefully you guys can point me in the right direction.

I have a simple app which needs to periodically check the web for results. Reading around, it seemed using an AlarmManager was the most appropriate way to schedule an event to happen as opposed to a background service.

The main activity shows the most recent result of the web query, when that query took place, and the next time it's due to re-query.

THe problem I'm having is that I didn't realise the BroadcastReceiver ran in a separate process...when the receiver updates the applications last query result, last check time and next check time, it's obviously not doing it in the copy of the object the app uses ;-) so it looks stale when I open the app...

I've tried Static variables on a StateManager class that are set from the broadcastrecevier and main activity, i've tried specifying the StateManager to be an  Application subclass and specifying that as the android:name in the manifest...both seem to end up with distinct copies so the state updated from the broadcastreceiver isn't the state that the app sees.

NOw I'm beginning to understand what's happening...I'm struggling to understand the best way to resolve it.

Using a SQLLite DB to persist state is going to be too mcuh trouble because I want to store an object graph and it appears you can't do that yet (even if SQLLite stores blobs, the android interface doesn't cover it yet ?). I obviously don't want to spend hours on O-R mapping either.

I 'Do' currently raise a notification through the notificationmanager when the web query highlights a need, and that allows me to pass the intent and extras through to the app..so that part works for me...however, when the webquery returns a result that doesn't need notifications generated, I have no 'path' back to the application to give it the next check time, and I dont' want to bring the app forward just for the sake of having a way to pass extras to it.

I guess the crux of the problem is that I want, 
from a broadcastrecevier, to persist an object somewhere that my app can retrieve when it's live
or 
have a broadcastreceiver perform work within the app process (without bringing the app to the foreground) so that any static variable changes are made to instances that the activity use.

if the best way is to write this as a service, then so be it (if that's the case, before I start coding..does the service run in the same process as the application or will I get similar 'it's not doing what a singleton was supposed to do' problems that I've been having with the broadcastreceiever!)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I'd specified `android:process=":remote"`  in the receiver section of the app manifest. Removing that makes the Alarm run int he apps thread which resolved the issue.